# Can you catch a connection error?

Tags: javascript, php, html, connection

I tried a lot of things to catch the error of this code but somehow I couldn't catch its error.

I have tried the `try` and `catch(err)` method but the error just pops up. Can't find an article on how to catch server connection errors either. They pop up in my console log but I can't seem to catch them. Here is what I've tried so far... well one of the ways I tried.

```
function timrec(){
try{
var time;
var inter1sec = setInterval(frame, 1000);
function frame() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        time = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Date is: "+time.d+"-"+time.m+"-"+time.y+" <br> Time is: " +time.h+":"+time.mi+":"+time.s+ " <br> day of the week is: "+ time.dow + "<br>";

};  }

xmlhttp.open("GET", "date.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
}
catch(err){
alert("Warning! Connection error! Server might be down!");
}
}
```

I use the code to get the time of the server by intervals but can't seem to catch its error when I try and refresh my WAMP server to simulate a server connection failure.

Is it even possible to catch that?

If it's possible can ya share? And if it's not... thennnnn this'll be a fail. Either that, or my professor just threw me a trick question or something. Not gonna be the first time tho. :/

Comment: `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {` if this does not happen, then its an error. You probably just want an else statement there

Comment: What do you mean "connection error" exactly?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Mehul Mohan tried that but it just repeats it over and over again about 3 times before posting the same error. :/ and to anied, I think it's already given in the question.

Comment: @Arkonsol check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.google.com", true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {  
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {  // request completed. we have some results
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {  
          console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)  
        } else {  
           console.log("Oops", xmlhttp.statusText);  
        }  
    }  
}; 

xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: thanks dude. this actually worked. Now i know what i was missing... thank you again!